# How to restart Android app in Android 10 after few seconds

Tags: android, restart

I want to restart application after some seconds, following code worked in Android 8, but in Android 10 device nothing happens. Is ANY consideration is needed in Android 10?
Here is the code worked in Android 8

```
Context mContext = getContext();
final int DELAY_I_WILL_BACK = 60;
. . .          
Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, mPendingIntentId, mStartActivity, 
       PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + DELAY_I_WILL_BACK*1000, mPendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```

I tried *mActivity.finishActivity(1);* just before *System.exit(0)* but still does not working.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I have the same problem with android 10. I know this code works for android 8 but not with android 10. As Google has restrictions for lunch an activity or service from the background I am looking for alternative solution.

Comment: not yet  resolved  -_-

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
private static final int MAGICAL_NUMBER = 2323 ;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 3000;

private void restartAppAfter10sec () {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                restartApp();
            }
        },SCAN_PERIOD);
}

private void restartApp() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
      int mPendingIntentId = MAGICAL_NUMBER;
      PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 
      mPendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) 
      getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, 
      mPendingIntent);
      System.exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Note that the solution doesn't work on android 10 and above https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts.

Comment: Yes, you're right " I am also searching answer for this question